# Upgrade from 3.4 to 3.7.3 causing 500 error when trying to send email

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.7

After upgrade of Joomla on last version i have following problems:

- I cant send contact information form from Breezing forms. I get 500 Server error: Internal Server Error
- I cant send user email notifications from administration area. I get 500 Server error: Internal Server Error

In PHP log files i see this error message:  mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds. I tried to increase some values from fcgid, but i it didn't solve my problem:

```
FcgidBusyTimeout 300
FcgidIOTimeout 250
```

There are no useful errors that i could start from. Does anyone have any experience on solving this kind of problems?

How could i debug this?

Joomla is now running on: PHP 5.4.28-1+deb.sury.org~lucid+1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have updated all the extensions on your site as well, what do you see if you set the error reporting to "Maximum" in your configuration settings? Do you see an actual error or the same "Internal Server Error"?

Also, it might be that your server configuration changes are not taking effect, it is a good idea to check with your host to see if they are working or not.

One last thing, have you tried tinkering with your mail settings in the global configuration?